# widget force closes but logcat tells me nothing

Tags: android, service, android-widget

Hi
I've created a home screen widget.
it works great on my devices but crashes on other at (seemingly) random intervals, i tried to study the logcats that these users send me but i can't seem to find what is the error/exception that causes the force-closing

here's 1 log for an example:

```
 I/ActivityThread(29303): Publishing provider 

com.facebook.katana.provider.UserStatusesProvider: com.facebook.katana.provider.UserStatusesProvider
I/ActivityThread(29303): Publishing provider com.facebook.katana.provider.PhotosProvider: com.facebook.katana.provider.PhotosProvider
D/dalvikvm(29303): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3424 objects / 203960 bytes in 51ms
D/dalvikvm(29303): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2369 objects / 136048 bytes in 58ms
D/dalvikvm(29303): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 875 objects / 52040 bytes in 73ms
D/dalvikvm(29303): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1530 objects / 447680 bytes in 38ms
D/dalvikvm(   86): GC_EXPLICIT freed 23778 objects / 1131048 bytes in 132ms
I/Gmail   (25020): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 1804642, normalSync: true
D/GTalkService(  196): [RosterMgr] roster not modified
D/GTalkService(  196): [OtrMgr] OTR not modified
D/AccelerometerListener(  167): orientation: horizontal
D/PhoneApp(  167): updateProximitySensorMode: releasing...
E/Sensors (   86): CAPELLA_CM3602_IOCTL_ENABLE error (I/O error)
I/power   (   86): *** set_screen_state 1
D/SurfaceFlinger(   86): Screen about to return, flinger = 0x1fe220
D/GoogleLoginService(  196): onBind: Intent { act=android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator cmp=com.google.android.gsf/.loginservice.GoogleLoginService }
D/InCallScreen(  167): onResume()...
D/PhoneApp(  167): disable status bar
D/PhoneApp(  167): StatusBarManager.DISABLE_EXPAND
D/InCallScreen(  167): - onResume: initial status = SUCCESS
D/InCallScreen(  167): setInCallScreenMode: NORMAL
D/InCallScreen(  167): syncWithPhoneState()...
D/PhoneUtils(  167): dumpCallState():
D/PhoneUtils(  167): - Phone: Handler{44954ab8}, name = GSM, state = OFFHOOK
D/PhoneUtils(  167):   - FG call: ACTIVE isAlive true isRinging false isDialing false isIdle false hasConnections true
D/PhoneUtils(  167):   - BG call: IDLE isAlive false isRinging false isDialing false isIdle true hasConnections false
D/PhoneUtils(  167):   - RINGING call: IDLE isAlive false isRinging false isDialing false isIdle true hasConnections false
D/PhoneUtils(  167):   - hasRingingCall false hasActiveCall true hasHoldingCall false allLinesTaken false
D/PhoneUtils(  167):   - Ringer state: false
D/InCallScreen(  167): updateScreen()...
D/InCallScreen(  167): - updateScreen: updating the in-call UI...
I/power   (   86): *** set_screen_state 1
D/PhoneApp(  167): updateWakeState: callscreen true, dialer false, speaker false...
D/PhoneApp(  167): updateWakeState: keepScreenOn = false (isRinging false, isDialing false, showingDisc false)
D/skia    (   86): purging 193K from font cache [8 entries]
D/CallNotifier(  167): stopRing()... (OFFHOOK state)
D/Ringer  (  167): stopRing()...
D/Ringer  (  167): - stopRing: null mRingHandler!
D/InCallScreen(  167): onPhoneStateChanged()...
D/InCallScreen(  167): updateScreen()...
D/InCallScreen(  167): - updateScreen: updating the in-call UI...
D/PhoneApp(  167): updateWakeState: callscreen true, dialer false, speaker false...
D/PhoneApp(  167): updateWakeState: keepScreenOn = false (isRinging false, isDialing false, showingDisc false)
D/InCallScreen(  167): updateScreen()...
D/InCallScreen(  167): - updateScreen: updating the in-call UI...
D/AndroidRuntime(29278): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(29278): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7f0)
D/AccelerometerListener(  167): orientation: vertical
D/PhoneApp(  167): updateProximitySensorMode: acquiring...
I/power   (   86): *** set_screen_state 0
D/InCallScreen(  167): onPause()...
D/InCallScreen(  167): dismissAllDialogs()...
D/PhoneApp(  167): re-enable status bar
```

i believe that this block is where the force-close is done but i have no idea why:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(29278): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(29278): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7f0)
```

usually the next line is a stack-trace or something but in this case i get nothing.

please help me.
I thank you in advance.

Edit: eventually i realized i had to view the whole logcat directly (i tried alogcat for this log) and i found the problem that was simply NUllPointerExceptions that were not caught.
once i caught these exceptions and dealt with their creators - everything was fine.

Comment: Whats this null here: D/Ringer  (  167): - stopRing: null mRingHandler!

Comment: To be honest i am not sure but as i pointed out i found the error in the end, but 10x for trying.

Comment: You should asnwer your own question and mark it answered. Rather than editing it. Keeps your stats up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Eventually I realized I had to view the whole logcat directly. (I tried alogcat for this log). I found the problem was simply `NullPointerException`'s that were not caught. Once I caught these exceptions, and dealt with their creators, everything was fine.